# Links not working with ng-bind-html on mobile

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ng-bind-html

I'm building a mobile app with Ionic using AngularJS.

In some of the views I would like to bind HTML code having multiple links, but somehow its not working on mobile.

In the browser it works just perfectly, but on mobile the link can not be clicked.

Text I would like to bind:

```
"Some text <a href="http://www.test.com" target="_blank">http://www.test.com</a>"
```

My code in HTML:

```
<p ng-bind-html="testDetails"></p>
```

$sanitize is available, ngSanitize has been added as a dependency

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
var appControllers = angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ngSanitize']); // Use for all controller of application.
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks I've found a solution.

Somehow simple `<a>` tags with href attribute does not seem to be working on mobile with ng-bind-html.

Instead, I used:

```
<a href="" onClick="window.open('http://www.test.com', '_system', 'location=yes')" 
target="_blank">http://www.test.com</a>
```

This just works perfectly, but it was necessary to bypass $sanitize in ng-bind-html by explicitly trusting the dangerous value (See AngularJS documentation).
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize

In Controller:

```
$scope.testDetails = '<a href="" onClick="window.open('http://www.test.com', '_system', 'location=yes')" 
target="_blank">http://www.test.com</a>'

$scope.deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet = function(sniptext) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(sniptext);
};
```

In HTML view:

```
<p ng-bind-html='deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet(testDetails)'></p>
```

---

Also I've found a good filter to do this work, if the data is received with simple `<a href="">`attributes:
https://gist.github.com/rewonc/e53ad3a9d6ca704d402e